# svn2git gives 'empty' directory

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I tried [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) to test a migration from svn to git.
My command looks like:

```
yes $PASS | svn2git https://my-svn.net/project/ --username $USERNAME
```

I execute this command on an Ubuntu 14.04 where git is installed. I perform this in `/home/myuser/svn2git/`.
After some waiting the execution of the commands end:

```
    ...
    A   src/xx
    A   src/xx
    A   src/xx
    A   src/xx
W: Killed
```

When I perform `ls -la` in this directory it shows nothing. But `du -sh` is telling me there is 230 MB inside the directory.

How can I see my to git converted folders?

Answer (score -1):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

The `svn2git` you use is based on `git-svn` and overcomes some of the drawbacks of `git-svn`, but most are still present.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: I will try to take a look. I've cloned and installed the prerequisites but the rulesset part seems maybe a bit difficult. I'm able to use an svn which is on another server? So using a URL?

Comment: No, you need access to the SVN repository on the filesystem. Either run the conversion on the SVN server, or if you have filesystem access (e. g. via FTP, SFTP, SCP, SSH, ...) copy over the repository directory or if not use the method described in the docs of https://github.com/hartwork/svneverever to get a local copy.

Comment: The rules files are acutally pretty easy to write, especially if you don't have special cases / layout. You can look at the KDE rulesets for examples.